# Property of subclass is undefined

Tags: typescript

I don't know why a property of my subclass is undefined after initializing. Am I missing something? I believe my syntax is correct, but I could be wrong. I've tried other threads here on Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

```
import { PriceRestriction } from "@/utils/Enums";
import TCGPlayerPriceModel from "./TCGPlayerPriceModel";

export class TCGPlayerSKU {
    skuId: string;
    productId: number;
    languageId: number;
    languageName: string;
    languageAbbreviation: string;
    printingId: number;
    conditionId: number;
    conditionName: string;
    dropDownDisplayName: string;
    conditionAbbreviation: string;

    /**
     *
     */
    constructor() {
        this.skuId = "";
        this.productId = 0;
        this.languageId = 0;
        this.languageName = "";
        this.languageAbbreviation = "", 
        this.printingId = 0;
        this.conditionId = 0;
        this.conditionName = "";
        this.dropDownDisplayName = "";
        this.conditionAbbreviation = "";
        
    }
}

export class SelectableTCGPlayerSKU extends TCGPlayerSKU {
    isChecked: boolean;
    price: TCGPlayerPriceModel;  <----- This property is always undefined.

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.isChecked = false,
        this.price = new TCGPlayerPriceModel(); 
    }
```

TCGPlayerPriceModel.ts

```
export default class TCGPlayerPriceModel {
    sku: string;
    lowestListingPrice: number;
    lowPrice: number;

    constructor() {
        this.sku = "",
        this.lowestListingPrice = -9,
        this.lowPrice = -9
    }
}
```

Example.ts

```
import {
  ImportedProduct,
  TCGPlayerSKU,
  SelectableTCGPlayerSKU,
} from "@/models/Product";

let sku = new SelectableTCGPlayerSKU();

sku.price.lowestListingPrice; // undefined
```

Comment: Seem to work for me. If I copy and paste your code into a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/w61bRW) I get `-9`. Please provides a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: To me it looks like you tried to provide a minimal reproducible example, but minimized it too much. To get a better MRE, try: 1) Removing irrelevant fields/properties; 2) Actually making the problem reproducible; 3) Renaming classes/files to things like `Foo` and `Bar` so that the name is more generic and search engines don't classify this as a search result for TCGs, players, SKUs, and whatever else they can find in this code (also, this makes it easier for us to read it)

Comment: @AlexWayne  You both are right. I've tried to formulate my question better here with additional context and simplified class names. Please see my better question here. TIA

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73874341/vue-property-of-subclass-array-is-undefined

Comment: CC: @pigrammer please see above. Thank you for your time as well.